# Command failing via python script but working manually

Tags: python

I am having this problem where the below command is failing via python script,if I try to run this command manually on the command-line on any linux box it passes,only through the script it is failing,any inputs on what is wrong here or tips to debug?

```
source= Popen(['source build/envsetup.sh'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
stdout,stderr=source.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
lunchcommand=Popen(['lunch 12'],stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
stdout,stderr= lunchcommand.communicate()
print "Printing lunch stdout and stderr"
print stderr

/bin/sh: lunch: command not found
```

Comment: What's the output of `which lunch` ? You should be using the full path in your script.

Comment: @DiegoBasch - Its not a unix utility..its a local script ,so which lunch will not give anything

Comment: `which` is not just for unix utilities. It will search your PATH for executables.

Comment: @DiegoBasch - Actally I just realized that "lunch" is a function name in the shell script being run(updated the question with the script) before running lunch command,so this shell script adds lunch functions to environment...I can see the shell script is successful,so not sure why lunch command is failing

Comment: The simple fix is to move it from a function to a standalone script.

Comment: @tripleee - unfortunately thats not an option now,am sure there are other ways..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually be using this:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen

the_command = '/path/to/lunch 12'
result = Popen(shlex.split(the_command))
```

Since `12` is an argument to `lunch` and not part of the command, `shlex` will automatically take care of splitting the command and its arguments.

You should pass `Popen` a list when you have a command and arguments together.  Make sure you really need `shell=True`? Do you know [what it actually does](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)?

Comment: you said "You should pass Popen a list when you have a command and arguments together."how is shlex doing that different? lunch 12 is also a command and argument,right?

Comment: Actually I just realized that "lunch" is a function name in the shell script being run(updated the question with the script) before running lunch command,so this shell script adds lunch function to environment...I can see the shell script is successful,so not sure why lunch command is failing –

Comment: That's because the environment is not preserved through the calls (note that `source` is a bashism and you are running the commands using `sh`).

Comment: thats right,is there a way to preserve enviroment?am thinking of putting these commands in a shell script and call from python...anyother ideas u have?

Answer (score 1):

Since `lunch`is a bash function defined in `build/envsetup.sh`, you could either create a bash script that sources `build/envsetup.sh` before calling `lunch 12`, or you could have `Popen` execute a bash command such as

```
bash -c "source /tmp/envsetup.sh && lunch 12"
```

For example:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

with open('/tmp/envsetup.sh', 'w') as f:
    f.write('function lunch() { KEY="$@"; firefox "www.google.com/search?q=${KEY}" ; }')
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('bash -c "source /tmp/envsetup.sh && lunch stackoverflow"'))
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Popen can take both strings and a list, but when you are passing in arguments (as is the case here), its best to pass them as a list so that shell escaping can be done properly.